# I need an algorithm to get the chromatic number of a graph

Tags: java, graph-theory

Given the adjacency matrix of a graph, I need to obtain the [chromatic number](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChromaticNumber.html) (minimum number of colours needed to paint every node of a graph so that adjacent nodes get different colours).

Preferably it should be a java algorithm, and I don't care about performance.

Thanks.

Edit:
recently introduced a fix so the answer is more accurately. now it will recheck his position with his previous positions.

## Now a new question comes up. Which will be better to raise his 'number-color'? the node in which i am standing, or the node i am visiting (asking if i am adjacent to it)?

```
public class Modelacion {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{

    //  given the matrix ... which i have hidden the initialization here

        int[][] matriz = new int[40][40];

        int color[] = new int[40];

        for (int i = 0 ; i<40;i++)
            color[i]=1;

        Cromatico c = new Cromatico(matriz, color);

    }
}

import java.io.IOException;


public class Cromatico {

Cromatico(int[][]matriz, int[] color, int fila) throws IOException{

        for (int i = 0; i<fila;i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j<fila;j++){
                if (matriz[i][j] == 1 && color[i] == color [j]){
                    if (j<i)
                        color [i] ++;
                    else
                        color [j] ++;
                }
            }
        }

        int numeroCromatico = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k<fila;k++){
            System.out.print(".");
            numeroCromatico = Math.max(numeroCromatico, color[k]);  
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("el numero cromatico del grafo es: " + numeroCromatico);

    }
}
```

Comment: how would you obtain the value manually?  whatever your answer, there's your answer!

Comment: @atk to obtain the cromatic number of a graph given the adjacency matrix.

Comment: Your algorithm is incorrect. For 0-2-3-1 it will compute a chromatic number of 3.

Comment: @Carlos: Do you understand what NP-Complete means? If you think you have an algorithm for this problem and that runs in O(n^2) time,  better look carefully, there is most likely a mistake.

Comment: well thank you for your comments, i got that about the NP-Complete, so i finally only proposed an approximation for the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Finding the chromatic number of a graph is NP-Complete (see [Graph Coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring)). It is NP-Complete even to determine if a given graph is 3-colorable (and also to find a coloring).

The wiki page linked to in the previous paragraph has some algorithms descriptions which you can probably use.

btw, since it is NP-Complete and you don't really care about performance, why don't you try using brute force?

Guess a chromatic number k, try all possibilities of vertex colouring (max k^n possibilities), if it is not colorable, new guess for chromatic number = min{n,2k}. If it is k-colorable, new guess for chromatic number = max{k/2,1}. Repeat, following the pattern used by binary search and find the optimal k.

Good luck!

And to answer your edit.

Neither option of incrementing the color will work. Also, your algorithm is O(n^2). That itself is enough to tell it is highly likely that your algorithm is wrong, even without looking for counterexamples. This problem is NP-Complete!

Answer (score 2):

Super slow, but it should work:

```
int chromaticNumber(Graph g) {
  for (int ncolors = 1; true; ncolors++) {
    if (canColor(g, ncolors)) return ncolors;
  }
}

boolean canColor(Graph g, int ncolors) {
  return canColorRemaining(g, ncolors, 0));
}

// recursive routine - the first colors_so_far nodes have been colored,
// check if there is a coloring for the rest.
boolean canColorRemaining(Graph g, int ncolors, int colors_so_far) {
  if (colors_so_far == g.nodes()) return true;
  for (int c = 0; c < ncolors; c++) {
    boolean ok = true;
    for (int v : g.adjacent(colors_so_far)) {
      if (v < colors_so_far && g.getColor(v) == c) ok = false;
    }
    if (ok) {
      g.setColor(colors_so_far, c);
      if (canColorRemaining(g, ncolors, colors_so_far + 1)) return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: where do i get that Graph class?

Comment: I merely postulated its existence, I don't actually know of one off hand.  5 seconds of googling for "graph java" found me a few possibilities.