# I'm trying to find a "bartender algorithm"

Tags: algorithm

I was solving some example questions from an old programming contest. In this question we get an input of how many bartender we have, and which recipe's they know. Each cocktail takes 1 minute to make and we need to calculate if the order can be finished within 5 minutes, using all bartenders.

The key to solving this problem is assigning cocktails as efficient as possible. And thats where I'm stuck, my current algorithm gives the order to the bartender who knows the least other recipes. But of course this isn't 100% correct yet. Could anyone point me in the right direction (or give me an algorithm name to google) which solves this "bartender problem"?

Comment: Assignment problem usually points to Hungarian algorithm. But I am not very clear about the problem you are trying to solve here...

Comment: Can you post the exact question never heard of the bartender problem and it sounds interesting. Google turned up nothing.

Comment: I can but I'd need to translate it, if you really want it I will.

Comment: Sounds like a scheduling problem.

Comment: Scheduling problems generally consist of identical "machines" (in this case bartenders), which isn't the case here.

Comment: Right, I take back what I said about Iarsmans being correct. This is actually a different problem than scheduling.

Comment: If you can model it with a directed acyclic graph, then you can take the dynamic programming approach! (Source: http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

This could be solved with a flow network.

- The source has edges to each bartender, with capacity 5.
- Each bartender have edges to each drink he/she can make, with capacity 5.
- Each drink have edges to the sink, with a capacity corresponding to the number that is ordered.

Compute the [maximum flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) from the source to the sink. If any order remains unfulfilled, there is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create a list of cocktails on the order, sequenced by how many tenders know how to make that cocktail

ie The order is for 
(2*CocktailA, 1*CocktailB, 2*CocktailC, 1*CocktailD)

CocktailA can be made by 4 tenders (Tenders A, B, C, D)
CocktailA can be made by 4 tenders (Tenders A, B, C, D)
CocktailB can be made by 3 tenders (Tenders A, B, C)
CocktailC can be made by 1 tender (Tender A)
CocktailC can be made by 1 tender (Tender A)
CocktailD can be made by 1 tender (Tender B)

Work backwards through that list, assigning jobs to tenders. If multiple tenders can make the cocktail, then pick the one with the least amount of jobs already assigned.

CocktailD = Tender B
CocktailC = Tender A
CocktailC = Tender A (again)
CocktailB = Tender C
CocktailA = Tender D
CocktailA = Tender B (again)

Tenders A and B both have 2 jobs, so the order will take 2 mins.

Comment: This seems to be the easiest solution to implement, I'm going to give it a try if this returns the correct result in all the test cases.

Comment: This will not work. The rule "pick the one with the least amount of jobs already assigned" does not assure that the optimal bartender will be chosen.

Comment: I don't think the algorithm is correct - it may be a heuristic in a search algorithm, but I don't think it can always determine the correct solution on first try.

Comment: There are two rules. One to sequence the tenders, then one to pick them. Do you have an example where this doesn't work?

Comment: @PaulG Paul, your algorithm is linear time. This is an NP-hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a vertex coloring problem. It is exactly analogous to the register allocation problem which is very well studied. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation. It can also be thought of as a set cover problem which is analogous to vertex coloring.

Of course, here we need not find the actual coloring, we just need to determine whether its cardinality is 5 or less. If the bartender graph can be colored in 5 or fewer colors, then the answer is Yes, otherwise No. Here is another nice paper describing the problem in terms of "tasks" and "days" and "machines": http://www.polymtl.ca/pub/sites/lagrapheur/docs/en/documents/NotesChap7.pdf.

Now, to figure this out, what is called the "chromatic number" or "chromatic index" of the graph, is NP-hard. In fact, someone has already asked on SO for an algorithm to find the chromatic number of a graph, but unfortunately did not get much of a response, see [Algorithm for Chromatic Number of a Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2926336/i-need-an-algorithm-to-get-the-chromatic-number-of-a-graph)

Just looking around the web I did find some code resources for doing colorings. One that can do this problem is called [SMALLK](http://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~joe/Coloring/Colorsrc/smallk.html). SMALLK can find colorings up to 8. Since we only need 5 for this problem this package can do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variant on the [college matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Resident_Matching_Program#Matching_Algorithm). Where drinks are students and bartenders are colleges. In turn it is a generalization of the [stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem), which might be of more use to you.

Comment: This is not a bipartite matching problem because bartenders can make multiple drinks within the 5 minutes.

Comment: It can be made into one, by cloning each bartender 5 times.

Comment: But a bartender cannot make two drinks at the same time

Comment: Each copy of the bartender can make one drink each.

Comment: Matching problems like stable marriage can be solved in polynomial time. This problem is a coloring problem which NP-hard.