# Lazy Bartender Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I found following problem in one of the interviews. Please suggest me the algorithm for this. I don't need code.

- There are `N` number of possible drinks.(n1,n2..)
- Has `C` number of fixed customers.
- Every customer has fixed favorite set of drinks.
- Bartender has to create least possible number of drinks to suffice need of all the customers

Example:

```
Cust1: n3,n7,n5,n2,n9  
Cust2: n5  
Cust3: n2,n3  
Cust4: n4  
Cust5: n3,n4,n3,n5,n7,n4    

Output: 3(n3,n4,n5)
```

Comment: The example is trivial to solve and does not represent the general case. So what should be solved ? Example or general ?

Comment: Looks like the [Stable marriage problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem). Have you checked anything about [matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)) problems and graph theory? A few things are also mentioned here: [I'm trying to find a “bartender algorithm”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17068783/im-trying-to-find-a-bartender-algorithm)

Comment: Thanks Yves.  Actually, I did not understand how the output in the example is achieved. It would be beneficial if the output can be explained.

Comment: Thanks @tgogos : Let me have a look on matching problems and the stable marriage problem. Thanks for response.

Comment: @tgogos : I think this problem is different from stable marriage problem. Two customers can get a same drink but two person cannot get married to one person.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's reformulate this problem. We have a bipartite graph `G(Drinks, Customers, E)`. Where edge `e(i, j)` is in `E` when drink `i` is in the favorite set of the customer `j`. And we want to find the minimum cardinality subset of `Drinks` to cover all `Customers` set.

This problem is a variation of [Set cover problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) (look at the [Hitting set formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation)). It is known to be `NP-hard`, so there is no known polynomial algorithm.

Depending on constraints of the particular problem it can be solved with simple brute-force algorithm or dynamic programming/memoization approach, but you should know the exact constraints then.

Comment: True, but here we have additional information about the graph (basically that there are two groups of nodes, and that you can only be linked to a node in the other group), so maybe it is a simpler case, that can be solved polynomially ?

Comment: @gdelab, unfortunately, bipartite graph version https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation is `NP-hard` as well.

Comment: Yes this problem can be solved by set cover algorithm. Thanks @DAle

Answer (score 0):

For those who want a solution which is iterative trial rather than theoretical...
and it's rather specific to the problem than generic...

I have given the code at the end of explanation and I selected ruby because of its more plain English style and ruby code I didn't find available on the internet, but its a charm to read your code in almost plain English.....

I am giving the code since the problem is old enough that it's already solved over the internet. Anyways cheating the exam is not intended...

Again there are many dry methods to solve this yet my solution is little lengthy sometimes but it gives a nice iterative method to actually understand and solve the problem...

```
# Lazy Bar tenderer code
# A bar has m(represented by drinks variable) type of drinks and has n
# customers(represented by customers variable) having
# their personal preference of drinks known
# This is represented by a 2D array represented
# as the rows represent each customer and columns as their preferred drinks type
# We have a lazy bar tenderer who would like to make(or even learn) the least number of
# drinks so as to serve the customers their choice of drinks
# we have the array, m the number of drink types, and n the number of customers as the input
# we as supposed to give the least count of drinks the bar tenderer needs to make as 'count'
```

```
# Sample input

array = [
[0, 1, 3, 6],
[1, 4, 7],
[2, 4, 7, 5],
[3, 2, 5],
[5, 8]
]

n = 5
m = 9
```

```
# Sample output should be count = 2 (the drink number 5 and 1)
#

# We will make an array of m rows each representing the drink type number
# and n+1 columns where n columns are for customers with preference represented as
# binary value either 0 or 1
# and the +1 column for the sum of preferences for each drink row
#
# The arr for sample input is
#
#       0   1   2   3   4   Sum
#
# 0     1   0   0   0   0   1
# 1     1   1   0   0   0   2
# 2     0   0   1   1   0   2
# 3     1   0   0   1   0   2
# 4     0   1   1   0   0   2
# 5     0   0   1   1   1   3
# 6     1   0   0   0   0   1
# 7     0   1   1   0   0   2
# 8     0   0   0   0   1   1
```

```
#
# We will find the max value of sum ie the most preferred drink, so naturally the bar tenderer
# needs to know how to make it
# So we can eliminate the drink with the customers whom we can serve with the drink
# Now just increment the count variable count++
# and shortlist the array as below
#
#       0   1   Sum
#
# 0     1   0   1
# 1     1   1   2
# 2     0   0   0
# 3     1   0   1
# 4     0   1   1
# 6     1   0   1
# 7     0   1   1
# 8     0   0   0
#
# Now you may need to select the drink with maxim preference and
# go on...until all of the customers are served
# ie, till the array is empty or customers left is zero
# For the example thats it ... all are served with the two drinks, drinks 5 and 1
# Now lets go to the codes for that....
```

```
# The method to find the least number of drinks

def least_drinks_serve_all(drink_schedule, drinks, customers)
    array_for_elimination = Array.new(drinks){Array.new(customers + 1, 0)}
    # Now making the array for elimination process
    array_for_elimination.each_with_index do |row, i|
        row.each_with_index do |col, j|
            next unless drink_schedule[i] && drink_schedule[i][j]
            index_of_drink = drink_schedule[i][j]
            array_for_elimination[index_of_drink][i] = 1
        end
    end
    # adding the total preference of each drink as last column
    array_for_elimination.each_with_index do |row, i|
        sum = 0
        row.each_with_index do |col, j|
            sum += array_for_elimination[i][j]
        end
        array_for_elimination[i][customers] = sum
    end
    customers_left = customers # counter for tracking the number of customers left to be served
    least_drink_count = 0 # counter for least number of drinks to be served by the lazy tenderer
    while customers_left > 0
        index_to_eliminate = 0
        row_max_val = 0
        # loop through to find the row index with maximum sum
        array_for_elimination.each_with_index do |row, i|
            if array_for_elimination[i][customers] > row_max_val
                row_max_val = array_for_elimination[i][customers]
                index_to_eliminate = i
            end
        end
            least_drink_count += 1 # we found one drink that serves maximum customers at the end of 1 iteration
            customers_left -= row_max_val # we have served to row_max_val customers
            # for to eliminate the counted drink with its customers
            for i in 0..customers
                if array_for_elimination[index_to_eliminate][i] == 1
                    array_for_elimination.each_with_index do |row, j|
                        if array_for_elimination[j][i] == 1
                            array_for_elimination[j][i] = 0
                            array_for_elimination[j][customers] -= 1
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    return least_drink_count
end
```

Given Input values:

```
drink_schedule =
[
[0, 1, 3, 6],
[1, 4, 7],
[2, 4, 7, 5],
[3, 2, 5],
[5, 8]
]

customers = 5
drinks = 9

It gives output as:
2
```